# Check if relations exists for a parent node before deleting it so that we don't have any orphan child node

Tags: php, laravel

Here I am trying to delete a parent node but only if it doesn't have any child node. Please review this code.

**PostController.php**

```
/**
 * Delete the given post.
 * 
 * @param  int $post_id
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \App\Exceptions\RelationExistsException
 */
public function deletePost($post_id)
{
    $relations = ['tags', 'comments'];

    $hasRelations = $this->postRepo->hasRelations($post_id, $relations);

    if ($hasRelations) {
        throw new RelationExistsException($relations);
    }

    $this->postRepo->delete($post_id);
}
```

**RepositoryTrait.php**

```
/**
 * Check if any relation exists.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @param  array  $relations
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasRelations($id, array $relations)
{
    if (count($relations) == 0) {
        throw new \Exception('No relation is provided.');
    }

    $modelName = $this->model;

    $query = $modelName::where('id', $id);

    $query->where(function($q) use($relations) {
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            $q->orHas($relation);
        }
    });

    return $query->exists();
}
```

**RelationExistsException.php**

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class RelationExistsException extends Exception
{
    /**
    * Create a new exception instance.
    *
    * @param array $relations
    * @return void
    */
    function __construct($relations)
    {
        parent::__construct(sprintf(
            'Cannot delete because there exists relations - %s.', implode(', ', $relations))
        );
    }
}
```

I have one more issue with the following code:

```
$modelName = $this->model; // contains '\App\Models\Post'

$query = $modelName::where('id', $id);
```

I have to save the `$this->model` in `$modelName` to use it with the `where` function. Is there a better solution for it. I have tried `{}`, `()` but nothing worked.

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/akaamitgupta/b5af25347aaf2c5686c716c862f3e8d7) for above code

Comment: If you want to reply to the advice given by an answerer, please post a comment instead of editing your question.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/42401).

Comment: It's too big for the comment. What to do for that?

Comment: @iCode You can make multiple comments and ask separate questions in each individual comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts below:

I would encourage you to think about validating parameters more thoroughly on your public methods.  For example, in `deletePosts()`, you do nothing to validate that you even have an integer value (or whatever) to work with.  You do it in some cases such as type-hinting for array and validating non-empty array on `hasRelations()`, but it is not consistent.  What if non-array is passed to your exception constructor? What if non-integer (or whatever) is passed to `deletePosts()`?

You may not think it matters now because you are currently working in this application area and understand where all the calls are made against these methods, but think about in the future when you try to leverage these classes in new ways.  The call patterns may be different.  If, for example, you introduce a buggy use case that passes a non-array to your exception class, you want that class to complain loudly, rather than silently fail so that you can focus your debugging efforts more quickly on the problem code.

---

> ```
> $relations = ['tags', 'comments'];
> ```

Why is this hard-coded here?  I would think this should, at a minimum, be a property on the class, if not derived from configuration.

---

> ```
> $hasRelations = $this->postRepo->hasRelations($post_id, $relations);
> ```

Consider placing this code in a try-catch block since `hasRelations()` can throw. I know that since `$relations` is hard-coded here that we would never expect to get into a state where that exception is thrown, however I think it best practice to always use try-catch block in such a case so that as someone working in this code, you have quick understanding of how methods you are calling might perform.  Who knows, maybe the implementation of `RepositoryTrait` changes at some point and throws exceptions for other reasons besides the passed relations parameter.

---

> ```
> throw new \Exception('No relation is provided.');
> ```

Consider throwing `InvalidArgumentException` if you want to be more specific here.  I actually find it a bit odd that you use custom exception types in the code calling this but not here.  It might call into question how you are using custom exceptions throughout the application.

---

Your custom exception seems to have a very limited use case. It really only exists to format the message string from a passed array, functionality that might rightfully live in the code where the exception is thrown not within the logic of the exception.

Is this message even meaningful to caller as is?  You can't tell what kind of relationship exists amongst the types provided, nor the specific ID's of the relationships that exist, so there is questionable value in preparing this specific message string vs. just a simple 'Cannot delete because this post has relations' message in the exception. You could easily provide this message in context of where the exception is thrown totally eliminating the need to override the constructor (or maybe even this class altogether).

Is this class going to be used elsewhere in your application?  If not, should it even exist (vs. using other exception types)? If so, are you always going to want to pass this class an array of relation types as parameter to format into message string?

I actually question whether you should even be throwing an exception here at all if a relationship exists.  Since you are specifically building this functionality, my guess is that you are expecting the application to handle deletion requests against posts that have relationships as part of normal operation of the application.  If so, should this really be an exception or just an alternate code path that needs to be followed to handle this condition?  Only if you truly never expect the application to be put into this state would it make sense to have this code throw an exception.

---

To your question about how to call model dynamically while avoiding having to set `$modelName`, you could use something like:

```
call_user_func($this->model . '::where', 'id', $id);
```

but I honestly find what you have in place to be easier to read, and I would not be concerned about the cost of having the additional variable in memory (that seems like a micro-optimization type of concern).

Comment: Thanks for the review. Can you modify the code in the question and tell how you would code it (if given a chance)? Also, since you have put so many questions on why this approach is being followed, some coded explanation to put some light on what use cases and what combinations would you really keep in mind when writing a code to handle this situation. :)

Comment: @mike Thx for your time and I appreciate this. Please check the updated question to some of the questions you have asked for.

Comment: Update is reverted. Will post in comments.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you to validate parameters on public methods but for some cases, I just don't find any use of validation. Like in `deletePosts()` method `$post_id` can be int or string and it will be handled in Laravel. And yes I missed it in exception constructor, I will make sure to check parameters in future.

Comment: `$relations = ['tags', 'comments'];`

My initial thought when I hard-coded this was that it doesn't tell anything about the model so I didn't put it as a property of the class. And I have to use it only in the delete method and not anywhere else so I hard-coded it.

Comment: `throw new \Exception('No relation is provided.');`

I like the idea to throw `InvalidArgumentException` here. And why I use custom exception is that I handle them in the `render` method of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class for API and Web accordingly as:

 `case ($e instanceof RelationExistsException): flash()->error($e->getMessage())->important(); return redirect()->back();`

Comment: For your question - 

"whether you should even be throwing an exception here at all if a relationship exists"

My answer is that I use them in the `render` method as described above so that I show the message to the user in as a flash message. I agree that current exception message gives no information so I will change it as your suggestion or try to find a way to shoe more specific error.

Comment: @iCode Not sure if it is standard behavior in Laravel (which I admit only limited knowledge of) to use the Exceptions as an end user messaging mechanism. If so, then by all means work within the way the framework wants you to work.  I typically think of exceptions and exception messages as something that should be meaningful to a developer in finding and investigating cases where the application gets into an unexpected state, not for end user messaging.

Comment: @iCode To your comment of not seeing use for validation.  That;s great that Larvel will interpret strings or integers appropriately for making DB queries, but validation goes beyond that.  What if no value is passed? What if an empty string is passed?  Right now you code will tend to silently fail as opposed to loudly proclaiming that somehow the application got into a bad state so as to pass an unexpected parameter.